# Grammarly is Not Supported

Tags: javascript

I want to disable to support of Grammarly on my website. I do it with

```
$("input,textarea,div[contenteditable=true]").attr("data-gramm_editor", "false");
```

it's working fine but when users go to my site and click on Grammarly i want to show similar to medium.com, quora.com

[image]
[image]

is it possible to show something like **mysite.com is not supported**

Comment: I assume by technical reasons they mean "security concerns". Unless they provide way for website to disable the extension, you cannot change or affect its behavior.

Comment: But some website like quora.com, medium.com and much more show this message than why not I am?

Comment: Chances are they do not know *and* do not care about this extension. They did nothing to prevent Grammarly from working properly.

Comment: For doing this you need to contact support of Grammarly he can do that for you from his side.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to show that, if Grammarly decides to do so. Grammarly configured differently based on the domain, they will disable the check for some domains. You can find a little more details here: https://medium.com/@chloe_75253/how-grammarly-bashed-our-test-site-bb800422f151.You can contact them for help, however, I can't ensure you that will work. Chances are they won't include your site to their `config.json`.